# Minidump file summary accessing heap information

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dump

How do I access `Heap Information` from `Minidump File Summary`. I using `Visual Studio 2013` and new to dump files, this file was produced by `Windows Task Manager` selecting the process and creating a dump file.

[Screenshot below might explain better what I am trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SJd7.png)
[image: Img]

Comment: Sorry, but, your screen shot is too small to read.  What is it that you are looking to do?

Comment: @rrirower Added link that opens image

Comment: Again, what information are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to click the "Debug with Native Only" link on the right. After that, it'll fire up the debugger. You can look at local variables if it captured them. You can open the memory window to see heap info but probably need to know the general address range you're interested in.